# Wordpress wp_redirect not redirecting

Tags: php, wordpress

Hello guys badly need help here, I have created a custom template in wordpress. Now I also used a session variable to check status which I placed in the index.php, if session variable is 1 then redirect to a specific php file. But wp_direct() doesn't seem to work when I uploaded and installed the custom theme on my wordpress site. Check my codes:

```
<?php
session_start(); 
if ((isset($_SESSION['stat']) && $_SESSION['stat'] == '1')) {
wp_redirect('http://example.com/wp-content/themes/customtheme/newpage.php', 301);
exit;
?>
```

Code above only displays a blank page. Any help would be much appreciated.

UPDATE [SOLVED]: I managed to fix it, instead of using wp_redirect() I used a javascript method for redirection. Working code:

```
<?php
session_start(); 
if ((isset($_SESSION['stat']) && $_SESSION['stat'] == '1')) {
echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href = "http://example.com    
/wp-content/themes/euro/newpage.php";</script>';
?>
```

Comment: you need to try else with other redirect another location also check your session condition is correct

Comment: you have to pass page url.

Comment: session condition is correct..how can I pass page url?

Comment: like site_url('?page_id=11');

Comment: can you post a complete example? I am a newbie in Worpress.

Comment: wp_redirect('http://example.com/?page_id=10');

Comment: you need wp_redirect('http://example.com/wp-content/themes/customtheme/newpage.php', 301); replace with wp_redirect(site_url('?page_id=11'));(your newpage.php id)

Comment: what should be the page_id if the target page is newpage.php?

Comment: you need to create a page in admin and choose your template to embed this link  and get your page id in the url

Answer (score 0):

First you have assign newpage.php template in your page and then after you have to pass page id  in url which you are assigned page newpage.php template. Here i passed "10".

```
<?php
session_start(); 
if ((isset($_SESSION['stat']) && $_SESSION['stat'] == '1')) {
wp_redirect('http://example.com/?page_id=10', 301);
exit;
?>
```

Comment: how can I set the page id of newpage.php?

Comment: Create a new page. go to All pages > pages and assign template name as newpage.php now you can get this page id and this id you have to pass in url

Comment: Go to admin>pages>add new>enter page title, Template (choose your template from right side option below publish) then publish it after publish click on get shortlink button near page title and get page id (?p=30)

Comment: I cant use this option since newpage.php is a custom page inside the theme folder. Instead of redirecting through page id is there a way to redirect to a specific url?

Answer (score 0):

Try following code May be this will help,

```
session_start(); 
if ((isset($_SESSION['stat']) && $_SESSION['stat'] == '1')) {
    ob_clean();
    wp_redirect('http://example.com/wp-content/themes/customtheme/newpage.php', 301);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: I doubt, I used session variable and was able to echo it's value in index.php. The only problem is redirecting to a specific url from index.php.

Answer (score 0):

Make this file "newpage.php" as a template with name "newpage" and then create a page in backend then use this template for that page and then use the url of that page in  wp_redirect() function.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this functional as per below:

```
ob_clean();
$url = get_home_url() . '/login';
wp_redirect($url);
exit();
```